# How to create link in HTML that download that file

Tags: html, linux

I have http://192.168.230.237:20080 Server
file located on "/etc/Jay/log/jay.txt"

I tried with "http://192.168.230.237:20080/etc/Jay/log/jay.txt" this link gives me "404 NOT Found"

Here I can I link my file to link

Comment: Thankfully, the server doesn't expose the entire filesystem to the public. If you want to serve files from /etc/Jay/log, you have to set up the server accordingly.

Comment: linux is case-sensitive, is the directory Jay or jay? also, if you go to that url in your file system `/etc/Jay/log/jay.txt` from where the site is hosted, is it a real file?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP server will have a configuration option somewhere (Apache HTTPD calls it `DocumentRoot`) which determines where `http://example.com/` maps onto the filesystem of the computer.

Commonly this will be `/var/www/`.

Unless you change it to `/` (which would expose your entire filesystem over HTTP and is very much not recommended), you can't access arbitrary files on the computer.

`/etc/` is used to store configuration information for software installed on the computer. It should almost never be exposed outside the computer.

The best solution to your problem is probably:

1. Look at the configuration of your HTTP server and identify the document root (e.g. `/var/www/`)
2. Move your website files to that directory

If you really want to expose files under `/etc` via HTTP then you could also *change the document root*.

Your webserver might also support features like [Apache HTTPD's `Alias` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/urlmapping.html) which allows you to map a URL onto a file that can be outside the DocumentRoot.